# Mapping byte[] to BLOB in jOOQ becoming NULL in the query

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm trying to map a `byte[]` in Java to a BLOB field in my MySQL database. Here's the relevant code:

```
public void update(IUser data) {
    UserRecordExt user = <get user>;

    // copy other fields over
    user.from(data, USER.OTHERFIELD, USER.OTHERFIELD2);

    if (data instanceof IUserExt) {
        String avatar = ((IUserExt) data).getAvatarUrl();
        if (avatar != null) {
            user.setAvatarUrl(avatar);
        }
    }

    /* **** */

    user.update();
}
```

- `IUser` is the interface generated by jOOQ for our SQL table.
- `IUserExt` is an extension of that interface, with support for a `avatarUrl` used by our API to temporarily store data.
- `UserRecordExt` extends the `UserRecord` and implements `IUserExt`.
- `getAvatarUrl()` receives a base64 encoded string from our API call.
- `setAvatarUrl() converts this string to a`byte[]`, and stores it under`UserRecordExt.avatar`.

The field in my database which I'm trying to save to is `avatar`, and when I reach `/* **** */` in the debugger, I can see the `avatar` property is present and is a populated `byte[]`.

My problem is that when `user.update()` is called, the generated SQL query I can see in the console has `avatar` set to `NULL`. I'm absolutely clueless as to what the reason for this could be, losing faith in jOOQ a little here as I'd expect any fields present in my `user` object when I call the update to be written to the DB.

Any ideas?

---

Here's the code for `setAvatarUrl()`:

```
public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    try {
        this.avatar = avatarUrl.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("failed to getBytes() on avatar");
    }
}
```

(The error message isn't how the exception should be handled, however looking at logs this isn't the point of failure. The `byte[]` is generated OK.)

Comment: Don't lose faith in jOOQ. I don't think there's a bug as severe as this that has gone unnoticed for the last 6 years... There's some piece of information missing in your question, namely how this works: *"setAvatarUrl() converts this string to a byte[]"* Could you shed some light on this? Did you implement a converter?

Comment: The idea is that we store a BLOB in the database for an image, and when we pull it out we convert to a base64 encoded image before sending it to the client. The reverse also happens when a user wants to update the image. I'll add that code to my question.

Comment: The difficulty is that we'd like to support a fallback in the case of no avatar, generating an image based on other columns. I've had a look at the `Converter` class and it looks like the way to go, if it wasn't for this extra requirement. I'll try implementing it anyway! Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that this is close to impossible to diagnose from your point of view. Whilst I've seen you recommend against changing your schema to support a framework, we're in the middle of a database upgrade regardless! Perhaps we should be pushing the fallback case (i.e. generating an avatar based on an email/facebook username) into the database so that we can use the converter as you suggested.

Comment: With jOOQ, you certainly don't need to change the schema according to any of jOOQ's rules. I just believe that you made a small mistake in your `setAvatarUrl()` setter ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29513032/521799))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your current approach is here:

```
public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    try {
        this.avatar = avatarUrl.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("failed to getBytes() on avatar");
    }
}
```

You apparently added some sort of `avatar` field in your subtype `UserRecordExt`. But how is jOOQ supposed to know about it, when you call `update()`? That value isn't really part of the record.

A better implementation would be:

```
public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    try {
        // This will actually set the AVATAR value on the record itself!
        super.setAvatar(avatarUrl.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("failed to getBytes() on avatar");
    }
}
```

The above probably answers your question right now. On the other hand:

1. This is not how you download a resource over the wire. This will just generate a binary representation of the URL, not of its content ;-)
2. I personally don't think that you should implement this kind of logic in the data access layer, but that discussion is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Yep, calling `setAvatar()` on the parent class worked great. Thank you! Our images are stored as BLOBs, which are base64 encoded and loaded on the client. It works fine, albeit perhaps not making best use of caching.

Comment: I'm going to implement the converter at some point however, seems like a much cleaner way of doing it. Learning jOOQ by performing upgrades on an existing project! :)